# How can I create an activity that uploads data to a xampp server

Tags: java, android

How can I make a database in xampp that can store data and be able to link it to an App that will use the same database

Comment: Am i Right, when i assume that you want to start a xampp Server which runs a Database for example mysql from which you can download Images?

Comment: Yes You are right

Answer (score -1):

use https://ngrok.com/ to get proper URL to for your local server then you can add that URL to your android app